# Docker overwrites files?

Tags: docker

I have very simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress

RUN touch /var/www/file1.txt
RUN touch /var/www/html/file2.txt
```

It create 2 files, file1.txt to /var/www/ and file2.txt to /var/www/html/

Then I build it: `docker build -t 'wp' .`
and after that I run it:

```
=> docker run --name "wpcontainer" wp
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
```

Now if I look inside:

```
=> docker exec -it wpcontainer bash
root@e00c5da7ba67:/var/www/html# ls
index.php    wp-activate.php     wp-comments-post.php  wp-cron.php    wp-load.php   wp-settings.php   xmlrpc.php
license.txt  wp-admin        wp-config-sample.php  wp-includes    wp-login.php  wp-signup.php
readme.html  wp-blog-header.php  wp-content        wp-links-opml.php  wp-mail.php   wp-trackback.php
root@e00c5da7ba67:/var/www/html# cd ..
root@e00c5da7ba67:/var/www# ls
file1.txt  html
```

`file2.txt` isn't there. It is gone probably because wordpress was copied over it?

**How can I have both, wordpress and `file2.txt` inside of `/var/www/html/`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the entrypoint script at https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/0a5405cca8daf0338cf32dc7be26f4df5405cfb6/php5.6/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L33 it is setting up wordpress from `/usr/src/wordpress`. So, you could copy the file to `/usr/src/wordpress` instead and it would then end up in the resulting `/var/www/html` when copied by the entrypoint script.